# Combine SQL results into comma separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

given this example query

```
select student.name, student.code, student.age, studentClass.classId
from student
inner join studentClass
on student.studentId == studentClass.studentId
```

returns results like this

```
student.Name    student.code   student.age   studentClass.classId
---             ----           ---           ---
Jeremy          381            20            14
Jeremy          381            20            5
Jeremy          381            20            11
Sarah           920            23            20
Sarah           920            23            3
```

how could I alter the query to join all rows by student.name and have classId be comma separated?

```
student.Name    student.code   student.age   studentClass.classId
---             ----           ---           ---
Jeremy          381            20            14,5,11
Sarah           920            23            20,3
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: This is a an easily found duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SQL Server 2017 or higher, you can join and use `string_agg()`:

```
select
    s.name, 
    s.code,
    s.age,
    string_agg(sc.classId, ',') classIds
from student s
inner join studentClass sc on sc.studentId = s.studentId
group by s.name, s.code, s.age
```

Comment: I think if only class ids needed in comma-separated hence addition need of joining the table student class is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query using `FOR XML PATH('')`.

```
create table Student(StudentId int identity(1, 1)
 , Name varchar(20)
 , code int
 , age  int
 , classId int)

 insert into Student values
('Jeremy', 381, 20, 14),
('Jeremy', 381, 20, 5),
('Jeremy', 381, 20, 11),
('Sarah',  920, 23, 20),
('Sarah',  920, 23, 3)

 create table StudentClass (classId int
 , className varchar(20))

insert into StudentClass values
(3,  'Class A'),
(5,  'Class B'),
(10, 'Class C'),
(11, 'Class D'),
(14, 'Class E'),
(14, 'Class F')

SELECT Name, Code, Age, classId = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Cast(classId as varchar(3))
           FROM Student b 
           WHERE b.Name = a.Name
             and b.Code = a.Code
             and b.age = a.age
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Student a
GROUP BY  Name
   , Code
   , Age
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4dc5863cda900afc65fa61d8730e168) demo.